# JQuery Mobile - Safari Error: attempted to call method 'bindRemove'

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, safari

I have a problem with JQuery Mobile, I get the following error in Safari: 
`Error: cannot call methods on page prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'bindRemove'` 
as a result of this the next page does not load correctly.

Code:

```
<body>

<script>
$("body").on("swiperight",function(){
  $.mobile.changePage('home.html', {transition: "slide", reverse: true});
});              
</script>

<div data-role="page">
  <div id="home" class="footer">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-transition="slide" data direction="reverse">Previous</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

I need support in Safari because I am making an iOS webapp, it currently works perfectly in Google Chrome

JQuery Mobile Version: 1.4.4

Thanks

Comment: Pls post versions of jquery and JQM.

Comment: I am using JQuery Mobile 1.4.4

Comment: Try moving the script to head and make sure all tags are properly closed.

Comment: @Omar I have tried that and it didn't work, I have also tried `document` instead of `"body"` and created an on pagecreate function around the above swipe function. But none of these have worked.

Comment: When do you get that error exactly?

Comment: @omar when I swipe/click previous on this page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after spending ages fiddling around with the code I found a solution. Instead of using inline JQuery I made one file with both of my swipe functions. Here is my code:

```
$(document).on("swipeleft",function(){
  $.mobile.changePage('one.html', {transition: "slide", reverse: false});
}); 

$(document).on("swiperight",function(){
  $.mobile.changePage('home.html', {transition: "slide", reverse: true});
});
```